# cron/wget - Run page every 5 hours and 30 minutes

Tags: php, ubuntu-12.04, cron

I need help with 2 things. I'm creating a PHP page that restarts a game server every 6 hours through sending an RCON command (#restart) and I would like to have that page auto-refresh (Change case e.g http://mydomain.com/restart.php?cmd=#say&timeleft=30 and send another RCON Command to the server (#say) that says "Server restart in 30 minutes" at first, then the second time it says "Server restart in 10 minutes" and so on for 5 minutes and 1 minute. And when that time has passed (Approx 30 minutes), I want the page to send the restart command. I'm guessing that I need to set a cron job that runs the page with a 5 hour and 30 minute interval.

I have the PHP section done (RCON library and the commands aswell as cases (e.g http://mydomain.com/restart.php?cmd=#say&timeleft=30)) I have yet to figure out how to do this in PHP, or do I need to do it in jQuery or AJAX or something?
Thanks in advance! Regards, Tom.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is post a command that specifies the time for restart.. When you visit the page it should check if a restart is imminent, then display restart time - current time.

You can then just cron job the restart every 6 hours:

* */6 * * * wget http://mydomain.com/restart.php

Comment: Thanks for your qucik answer! Although, I need the #say commands to be sent before I restart the server so the players are ready for it, if I restart the server at once without the players knowing it will happen, some bad things can happen since the game itself isn't that well coded.

Comment: Maybe the PHP sleep(); would do?